# Trying to use a custom UIColor instance (ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicolor

What's wrong with my code?

```
- (IBAction)randomColour:(id)sender {

    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0

    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white

    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

    self.Label.textColor = [UIColor color];
    self.Label2.textColor = [UIColor color];
}
```

I have tried initialising the color variables and `UIColor` everywhere but I keep getting below error:

> no known class method for selector 'color'

even though it's right there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.Label.textColor = color; self.Label2.textColor = color;
```